# DropDownList in Footer not getting filled/bound

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a GridView which contains two DropDownLists. For the DataRecord the DropDownLists are filled/bound perfectly but for the Footer they remain empty/unbound. In both the DataRecord and Footer the DropDownLists have respectively the same SqlDataSource.  What could be the reason that the DropDownLists in the Footers are not getting filled/bound?

```
               <asp:GridView
                    ID="ExecutionGridView"
                    runat="server"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="ID"
                    Font-Names="Calibri"
                    Font-Size="Small"
                    OnRowCommand="ExecutionGridView_RowCommand"
                    OnRowDataBound="ExecutionGridView_RowDataBound"
                    OnRowDeleting="ExecutionGridView_RowDeleting"
                    OnRowUpdating="ExecutionGridView_RowUpdating" 
                    HorizontalAlign="Left"         
                    ShowFooter="true"               
                    Visible="False">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" />
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="headerClass" ForeColor="#408080" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#408080" />
                    <Columns>                            
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="30">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("ID") %>
                                <input type="hidden" name="ExecutionId" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Theme" SortExpression="ThemeID">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ThemesIDDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="ThemesSqlDataSource" DataTextField="Theme" DataValueField="ID" CssClass="ddl" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ThemeID", "{0:D}") %>' AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ThemesIDDropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ThemesSqlDataSource" DataTextField="Theme" DataValueField="ID" CssClass="ddl" ></asp:DropDownList>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Env" SortExpression="EnvironmentID">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="EnvironmentsIDDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="EnvironmentsSqlDataSource" DataTextField="Environment" DataValueField="ID" CssClass="ddl" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("EnvironmentID", "{0:D}") %>' AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="EnvironmentsIDDropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EnvironmentsSqlDataSource" DataTextField="Environment" DataValueField="ID" CssClass="ddl"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you share the complete mark up of the gridview?

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 0):

The FooterTemplate is not rendered with each row of gridview datasource, thus it can not bind using template. I think you should do it manually by code. You could check this link  [DropDownList control inside the GridView FooterTemplate](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-DropDownList-in-GridView-FooterTemplate-Footer-Row-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The FooterTemplate is not rendered with each row"

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typing mistake. I've edited my answer, please check

Comment: I found the problem. There was another TemplateField which had the same ID for both the DataRow and FooterRow.